# Is there a java -jar -P option?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, properties, executable-jar

When invoking a jar file locally (and passing in a property) I use:

```
java -jar j.jar --A=B
```

however, another user on a different system uses:

```
java -jar j.jar -PA=B
```

Note the `-P`. I don't know much about the other system but this does not work for me and I can't seem to find any docs that explain how this `-P` flag works. Anyone seen a reference to this anywhere?

Note the property is read in the application using Springs `Environment.getProperty("A")` method

Comment: Everything after `java -jar <jar-file>` are program arguments that go into the typical main method. Note that these are _not_ system properties.

Comment: Understood but in one env it picks up the property when passed in with the -P and in the other with --. Maybe the issue is in Spring which is used to read the property.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect that this is a property rather than a system property and that it is read through Spring.